# mitmproxy not working in El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: mitmproxy

I used the following command to install mitmproxy rather than using pip

> brew install mitmproxy

However when I try to run mitmproxy, I receive the below. What could be the cause for this? Does that mean I have 2 version of six and need to uninstall the outdated?

```
$ mitmproxy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mitmproxy", line 7, in <module>
    from mitmproxy.main import mitmproxy
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mitmproxy/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread  # PY3: We only need _thread.error, which is an alias of RuntimeError in 3.3+
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

Comment: you should add a <python> tag to your question. because this is an python error trace log